# How can i store more than 24,00,000 character in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I store `Base64` String in sqlite and for that I use these data types `TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT and LONGTEXT`. But when I cross limit of 23,00,000 character, Android is not able to read data of the table. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `24,00,000 character` ??? How much?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create code to break Strings apart at specific locations, and stitch it back together if you need to read the whole string.

```
String string = "abc def ghi jkl mno";
String ss[] = s.split(" ", 5);
// ss = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"};
```